# couchbase cluster log Audit Write Failure

Tags: logging, cluster-computing, couchbase

I'm using couchbase server of version 4.1.0-5005 Enterprise Edition (build-5005).

I have a cluster with two node. As below:
[image]

192.168.2.161 is the host node, the picture is from this node's Admin Console. But when i switch to the Log tab, seems there is an error:
[image]

I can't find the cause of the problem.

Is there any one who can help me?

Comment: The error seems to say the admin audit log cannot be written, but if that is not happening, then none of the logs should. So I would check to make sure the logs directory has the correct permissions on it for the couchbase user to write files? Also, Couchbase has no concept of host nodes. It looks like your two nodes are of different configuration. Is that true?

Answer (score 1):

Check the audit settings and make sure the 'couchbase' user has access to write to this folder.